# Java system time

Tags: java, time, systemtime

I have this code copied from one of questions from SO:

```
public static String getCurrentTimeStamp() {
  SimpleDateFormat sdfDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
  Date now = new Date();
  String strDate = sdfDate.format(now);
  return strDate;
}
```

I want to get only the system time and NOT the date. Then I must change second line of code to:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdfDate = new SimpleDateFormat(" HH:mm:ss") ;
```

Then,  DATE() must get the current time. Clear upto this point but I can't understand the format() function used.
I mean cant we simply output variable `now` instead of `strdate`?
Is it just because that the return type of function `getCurrentTimeStamp()` is String?

Please clarify and if there is any other simpler and one line code for getting system time alone, do share.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html you should check api

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I mean cant we simply output variable now instead of strdate.

Well you *could* return `now.toString()` - but that will use the format that `Date.toString()` happens to choose, whereas you want a specific format. The point of the `SimpleDateFormat` object in this case is to convert a `Date` (which is a point in time, without reference to any particular calendar or time zone) into a `String`, applying an appropriate time zone, calendar system, and text format (in your case `HH:mm:ss`).

You can still simplify your method somewhat though, by removing the local variables (which are each only used once):

```
public static String getCurrentTimeStamp() {
    return new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(new Date());
}
```

Or maybe you'd find it more readable to keep the variable for the date format, but not the date and the return value:

```
public static String getCurrentTimeStamp() {
    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    return format.format(new Date());
}
```

Personally I'd recommend using [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) instead, mind you - it's a much nicer date/time API, and its formatted are thread-safe so you could easily keep a reference to a *single* formatting object.

Comment: chaining . awesome !!  .. and i yes i came across you answer on joda time  in another post  as well . Thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
public static String getCurrentTimeStampwithTimeOnly() {
    return new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(new Date());
}
```

Helps you to do this.

Answer (score 0):

you can call this line  any time

```
Date now = new Date();
```

The now variable  will contain the current timestamp 
The format function just generates a String  from this timestamp

also take a look at the Calendar class ( Calendar.getInstance())